# pushing data into stack using LinkedList

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct nodeStack{
    char operator;
    struct  nodeStack *next;

};

typedef struct nodeStack node;

node *start=NULL;
node *tail=NULL;
int top=-1;


int isEmpty()
{

    if(top==-1)
        return 1;

}



void push(char c){
    node *tempNode,*tail;

    tempNode=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(tempNode==NULL){
        printf("Memory Unvailable\n");
        return;
    }

    tempNode->operator=c;
    if(start==NULL){
        start=tempNode;
        tail=start;
        tempNode->next=NULL;
        top++;
    }
    else{
        tail->next=tempNode;
        tempNode->next=NULL;
        tail=tail->next;
        top++;
    }

}


/*
struct node* pop(){
    if(top==-1){
        printf("stack is empty");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        node *temp;
        temp=start;
        while(temp->next!=tail){
            temp->next=NULL;
            free(tail);
            tail=temp;
        }
    }

}*/


void displayStack(){
    node *i;
    for(i=start;i!=tail;i=i->next){
        printf("%c -> ",i->operator);
    }
}


int main(){
    int i;
    int flag=1;
    char choice='y';
    printf("pushing data into the stack......");

   while(flag==1){
        char ch;
        printf("enter a character\n");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        push(ch);
        printf("want to push more operator (y\n)");
        scanf(" %c",choice);
        if(choice=='y')
            flag=1;
        else
            flag=0;

   }

    displayStack();

   return 0; 
}
```

Its giving me segmentation error when I am trying to run this.
It is accepting only one input and not taking further and at the same time it is giving segmentation error

Its giving me segmentation error when I am trying to run this.
It is accepting only one input and not taking further and at the same time it is giving segmentation error

Comment: Note: you don't *need* the tail pointer. Not for a stack, anyway.

Comment: You are not allocating "start" with any memory and that's why it's giving "Segmentation Error". Plus, you have declared "tail" in the push method; that's not needed!

Comment: @kiner_shah `start` is initialzied by `tempNode` when `start==NULL`. So it's not the reason of the problem

Comment: @kiner_shah `start` and co _are_ initialised, along with their declaration at global scope.

Comment: Ohh, my bad! I guess, I misunderstood that expression!

Comment: Please add `else` statement to `isEmpty` function.

Comment: @FredrickGauss Good catch. As is, if `top != 1`, that function invokes UB. So, OP, did you expect the compiler to guess what value you want to return otherwise? What you might want is simply `return top == -1` to convert the condition to a boolean return value. I mean, you don't even use that function here, but if you _did_, it would quickly cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
scanf(" %c",choice);
```

The second parameter should be passed as address, because `scanf` modifies it.

Try to modify with:

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
```

I'm not going to explain the reason in detail, because I think you just made a mistake since in some previous lines `scanf(" %c",&ch);` you've invoke right.

*Note: I'd avoid the space in the `scanf` string format.*

Comment: There are even more errors in the code other than this!

Comment: @kiner_shah Sure! Even the formatted string `printf("y\n")` which will prints a new line, and I suspect that is no the exact behaviour he wants. Anyway I answered the problem for the segmentation fault, the focused problem *asked* in the question. More comments and answers will be more than appreciate, I suppose :)

Comment: I don't think that was the cause to segmentation fault! The main reason was the double declaration of "tail" pointer in the original code I guess! @Biagio Festa. One in the push function and the other globally!

Comment: @kiner_shah I thought details were obvious, but they're not. I tested with *gcc* compiler and I can ensure you the segmentation fault the question describes is given by that: *"It is accepting only one input and not taking further and at the same time it is giving segmentation error".* In fact, `scanf` expects a pointer, and passing a char makes a seg. error. Try yourself and believe

Comment: I think you are right, according to the problem he mentioned. But, after we fix that, we can still get segmentation fault because of the two "tail" pointers! Try it out because I tried and it did lead to an error!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit modified code! Working code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct nodeStack{
    char op;
    struct  nodeStack *next;
}node;


node *start = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;
int top=-1;


int isEmpty()
{

    if(top==-1)
       return 1;
    else return 0;

}



void push(char c){
    node *tempNode;

    tempNode=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    tempNode->op=c;
    if(start==NULL){
        //start = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        start=tempNode;
        tail=start;
        tempNode->next=NULL;
        top++;
    }
   else{
        tail->next=tempNode;
        tempNode->next=NULL;
        tail=tail->next;
        top++;
    }

}


/*
 struct node* pop(){
   if(top==-1){
       printf("stack is empty");
        return;
   }

  else
   {
        node *temp;
       temp=start;
       while(temp->next!=tail){
          temp->next=NULL;
          free(tail);
          tail=temp;
      }
  }

 }*/


void displayStack(){
    node *i;
    for(i=start;i!=NULL;i=i->next){
        printf("%c -> ",i->op);
    }
}


int main(){
    int i;
    int flag=1;
    char choice='y', ch;
    printf("pushing data into the stack......");
    start=NULL; tail=NULL;
    while(flag){
        printf("enter a character\n");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        push(ch);
        printf("want to push more operator (y/n)");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
        if(choice=='y')
            flag=1;
        else
            flag=0;

       }

    displayStack();

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I've not checked the rest of it, but this still has the missing return value in `isEmpty()`, which causes UB... or would if the OP ever used it!

Comment: thanks alot @kiner_shah  for pointing minor  errors .
Since I have written C code after a long tym so I have missed these small things. Thanks....

Comment: Not a problem @Nitin! ;-)